# Is it a decreasing function of $x$?

Tags: functions, optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

I have following function of $x$ for $x>0$ $$f(x)=-(x+1)\exp(a+x)Ei(-a-x)-\frac{x}{a+x}$$ where $a>0$ and $Ei(x)$ is the exponential integral. I have plotted this function for different values of $a$ in WA and it appears that the function decreases with increasing values of $x$. Can we prove that $f(x)$ is a decreasing function of $x$? I will be very thankful to you for your help. The derivative of the above function is given as follows $$f'(x)=-\frac{(x+2)e^{a+x}(a+x)^2Ei(-a-x)+a(x+2)+x(x+1)}{(a+x)^2}$$

Edit:

Can we say anything if $0<a<1$?

Edit 2 (My goal and the way to achieve it):

Actually I am interested in finding the maximum value of $f(x)$. If  could show that $f(x)$ is a decreasing function of $x$ (which I think we can show through plotting for different values of $a$ but it may not be possible to show that result analytically) then it means $f(0)$ is the maximum value. Since I can not show analytically that $f(x)$ is decreasing function therefore in the following I devise a plan to show an upper bound on the maximum achievable value of $f(x)$. First I describe the following facts.

1- $\frac{-x}{a+x}$ is a decreasing function and its range is [0,1].

2- $g(x)=-(x+1)\exp(a+x)Ei(-a-x)$ is a product of one positive increasing function (i.e. $(x+1)\exp(a+x)$) and one positive decreasing function (i.e. $-Ei(-a-x)$). Therefore $g(x)$ is a quasiconcave function and we can find the maximum value of $g(x)$. This maximum value plus $1$ will be the upper bound on the maximum achievable value of $f(x)$.

If this reasoning is wrong then please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know what the derivative of Ei is?

Comment: @Squirtle yes I know that $\frac{dEi(x)}{dx}=\frac{e^x}{x}$. I have also verified it from WA.

Comment: @Squirtle what is the next step after finding the derivative of $Ei(x)$. What do you think can we prove that $f(x)$ is a decreasing function of $x$?

Comment: you must do the very boring task of applying the product rule and simply taking the derivative of the whole thing.  This is at least the first approach one should take with this problem

Comment: @Squirtle yes i completely agree with you. But I think even after taking derivative I can not say whether it is always negative.

Comment: What is the derivative?  Can you show your work?

Comment: @Squirtle I have added the derivative in my edited post. The denominator is always positive but the numerator is difficult to say any about

Comment: @Squirtle I have added my goal and the procedure to achieve that goal in my post. Please check if its right strategy or wrong strategy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really know the answer to your question but I thought it would manifest if you merely did what appears to be the only natural thing to do.  Sometimes we get lost in details and need a global picture, that's where I was trying to help.  I've upvoted though... and if I can think of anything new I'll post it.  But at the moment, nothing is coming to me.  Best of luck.